# How to get web url of Google Sheet from list based feed url?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In my application, I'm using the Google Sheets API to retrieve the list-based feed URL for a worksheet within a spreadsheet.

Is it possible to get the URL to the viewable worksheet on spreadsheets.google.com so I can have my application launch the user's default web browser to the exact, editable, worksheet?

From the API response I get, I see that the first URL in the `link` array with `rel` value of `alternate` gives me the link to the spreadsheet, but it opens up the spreadsheet at the first worksheet "tab", not the actual worksheet I want.   I'm curious if there is a way to get the URL to the worksheet itself.  That is, I want to open up a new browser to the worksheet based on the list-feed I'm using, and not just the first "tab" within the spreadsheet:

```
"link": [
  {
    "rel": "alternate",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{unique_key}/edit"
  },
  {
    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/{unique_key}/private/full"
  },
  {
    "rel": "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/{unique_key}/private/full"
  },
  {
    "rel": "self",
    "type": "application/atom+xml",
    "href": "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/{unique_key}/private/full?alt=json"
  }
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you could use an `onOpen()` trigger to make a certain sheet active when the spreadsheet opens.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would pass a parameter to that from the URL listed in the link object array.

Comment: The `onOpen()` function would need to retrieve a value/setting from somewhere instead of getting an argument passed to it.  To get a setting external to the spreadsheet, you could make an HTTP Request with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`.  You could also try to save a property to the spreadsheet document, then retrieve the document properties on open.  If you want to navigate to a certain sheet tab by user. you could require them to be logged into an Google Account, and try to get the user name?  I don't think there is a way to include a search string  parameter in the spreadsheet url then retrieve.

Comment: You can open another tab in the browser from HTML, but the browser would need to already be opened, and the user would need to be using something like a sidebar or dialog box inside of the spreadsheet.  Or a stand alone HTML Web App using Apps Script.  Where is your application running?

Comment: This seems overly cumbersome.  I guess Google doesn't have a standard way of doing this.  I'm going to leave the question open until there is a proposed answer.  And my app is running on a desktop application outside the browser.